# iOS 10 disable autorotation

Tags: uiviewcontroller, uikit, uistoryboard, ios-autolayout, autorotate

iOS 10 with Autolayout and Size classes is giving nightmares for trivial issues that were easy before. I launch my app in Landscape mode and want to disable autorotation till everything is configured, after which I manually trigger autorotation through API

```
   UIViewController.attemptRotationToDeviceOrientation()
```

But no matter what I do, the interface autorotates to portrait mode if device is held vertical. Here is what I have tried:

a. In Storyboard, I select landscape orientation in each of the traits(not sure if this really sets to landscape mode),

b. Set initial orientation in info.plist to landscape,

c. Return false in shouldAutorotate { },

d. Return only .landscapeLeft in supportedInterfaceOrientations

But even then the bounds of view come out to be (origin = (x = 0, y = 0), size = (width = 375, height = 667)). I want bounds to reflect width = 667 and height = 375. How do I do that?